# Export a variable vector from Mathematica to Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, vector, export, wolfram-mathematica

Let's say that I have a vector `v={{a1+b1,c1+a1, 3c1+a1},{1,2,a1}}` (in fact it has 100 rows) and I want to export it to MATLAB with `a1`, `b1` and `c1` as variables. What I have tried:

In Mathematica:

```js
v={{a1+b1,c1+a1, 3c1+a1},{1,2,a1}};
Export["v.csv", v, "CSV"];
```

Then, in MATLAB:

```matlab
vv = readtable('v.csv', 'PreserveVariableNames',true);
```

but it doesn't work. The output in MATLAB is shown in the picture

[image: Output]

I would like something like

```
vvv=@(a1,b1,c1)vv
```

in order to get some evaluations but I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it properly. I have just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what this line of code means in mathematical.

v={{a1+b1,c1+a1, 3c1+a1},{1,2,a1}};

but what you want like this

vvv=@(a1,b1,c1)vv

in Matlab call the anonymous function (you can search for more detail on Google)
but basically, You have to define your own variables, for example:

```
vv = readtable('v.csv') 
a1 = vv(2,1)   % vv(row, column)
b1 = vv(2,2)
c1 = vv(2,3)
vvv = @(a,b,c) a+b+c;     % this is anonymous function
eq_answer = vvv(a1, b1, c1)  % pass variable to anonymous function
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me add it in order to be more specific.  v is a 2x3 matrix and a1,b1,c1, are variables into v (more or less think in v[a1_,b1_,c1_]:={{a1+b1,c1+a1, 3c1+a1},{1,2,a1}}; I would like to export this expression as symbolic in MATLAB in order to evaluate the expression for several values of a1, b1 and c1.